# I can't deploy my ember app to AWS/S3 and getting Access Denied

Tags: ember.js, amazon-s3, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my ember.js app to s3 and so far, I have installed:

```
"ember-cli-deploy-build": "0.1.1",
"ember-cli-deploy-s3": "0.3.0",
"ember-cli-deploy-s3-index": "0.4.0",
```

My `config/deploy.js` looks something like:

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(deployTarget) {
  var ENV = {
    build: {}
  };

  if (deployTarget === 'development') {
    ENV.build.environment = 'development';

    ENV.plugins = ['s3', 's3-index', 'build'];

    // configure other plugins for development deploy target here
    ENV['s3-index'] = {
        accessKeyId:      "my_access_key_id",
        secretAccessKey:  "my_secret_key_id",
        bucket:           "my-bucket-index",
        region:           "ap-southeast-1"
    };

    // Configure Asset deployment to S3
    ENV['s3'] = {
        accessKeyId:      "my_access_key_id",
        secretAccessKey:  "my_secret_key_id",
        bucket:           "my-bucket-assets",
        region:           "ap-southeast-1"
    };
  }


  if (deployTarget === 'production') {
    ENV.build.environment = 'production';
    // configure other plugins for production deploy target here
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Now I made sure my access key id and my secret access key are working fine by uploading some files to the buckets using Cyberduck (policies and credentials working just fine).

However when I try to deploy using:

```
⇒  ember deploy development
- AccessDenied: Access Denied
- AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:350:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
odules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:617:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
AccessDenied: Access Denied
AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:350:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:617:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/info/code/my-ember-project/node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)Pipeline aborted
```

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running your code exactly the way you've pasted it here or do you switch the accesskeyid and secretaccesskey with your personal keys?

Comment: @YaronIdan eventually with my real keys ;) and I tested it and I'm pretty sure the keys are ok

Comment: @EkiEqbal were you able to solve this? I'm encountering the same thing right now and I was hoping you found a solution to this already.

Answer (score 1):

I was also running into this issue, and the fix for me was to add `acl: null` to my ENV.s3 credentials:

```
    ENV['s3'] = {
        accessKeyId:      "my_access_key_id",
        secretAccessKey:  "my_secret_key_id",
        bucket:           "my-bucket-assets",
        region:           "ap-southeast-1",
        acl:              null  // <-------------- Add this line
    };
```

You might also need to add it to your `ENV['s3-index']` hash, but I'm not sure.